# Add new lines in VBA email

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, html-email

I'm trying to send an email automatically through Excel, but the new line commands aren't working! I've tried `<br/>`,  `vbCrLf` and `vbNewLine`

```
.HTMLbody = "Hello" & vbNewLine & "Please find attached the above invoices and backup" & vbNewLine & _
            "Any queries please let me know" & vbNewLine & "Regards" & vbNewLine & Signature
```

It keeps just giving `Hello Please find attached the above invoices and backup Any queries please let me know Regards` as one line!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

May be you can try this instead:
Use

```
.HTMLbody = "Hello" & "<br>" & "Please find attached the above invoices and backup" & "<br>"
```

instead of vbnewline

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping the text in some rudimentary HTML tags.

```
.HTMLbody = "<html><body><p>Hello</p><p>Please find attached the above invoices and backup.</p>" _
     & "<p>Any queries please let me know</p><p>Regards</p>" & Signature & "</body></html>"
```

This assumes that the signature is already HTML formatted at a paragraph level. (not tested; no guarantees)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the email to be HTML try using .body instead of .html.

If you need the email to be html then you need to ensure the entire text is formatted with Html tags.  -  The easiest way to do this is to have you html code in a cell in your workbook and then reference this cell.

Comment: How would I do the referencing of a cell? `.Body = "Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1")` ?

Comment: if you send your self an email with the text you want then you can view the source of the email and copy the relevant section including html.

I have found it is useful to then use a convertor to convert this to "clean html" - This is standard html which removes all the microsoft  used tags.

Also if the only thing your are putting in the body of the email is those lines then there should not be any need for it to be sent as html.

Comment: The need for HTML is because of the signature, is there no way to do it in the VBA code itself?

Comment: Your referencing of the cell is correct (Or you can assign the cell value to a variable and use the variable -  `.body = VariablENAME` - If you have html tags in the text you need to use .htmlbody otherwise you can just use .body

Comment: You can create the correct HTML in VBA but I have never done so because AFAIK you would need to write a LOT more code. As i have never done this I would not be able to give any advice around this However I am sure if you search for "create HTML using VBA" in any search engine you will get examples.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers mate.  I ended up using VBA to do this:

```
strEmailBody = Replace(strEmailBody, vbCrLf, "<br>", 1)
```

and then

```
.HTMLBody = strEmailBody
```

This made the email look perfect.  It was plain text email content from a SQL query