# Display each email for manual editing before sending in a loop

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have over 200 emails to send with individual attachments.

The list is in Excel.

With code from elsewhere, I managed to open an email, with the attachment, email address, subject and body text.

I want the loop to pause once the email has been opened, so I can check the details, add in a signature etc. I then want the loop to move on to the next iteration but not until I click "Send".

Also, more minor point, but vbNewLine doesn't seem to create a new line?

```vb
Sub SendEmail_Example1()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Dim Attachment As String
Dim edress As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

    Attachment = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\" + Cells(i, 4)
    edress = Cells(i, 1)

    EmailItem.To = edress
    EmailItem.Subject = "Test Email From Excel VBA"
    EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "This is my first email from Excel" & _
      vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Regards," & vbNewLine & _
      "VBA Coder"
    Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    EmailItem.Attachments.Add (Attachment)

    EmailItem.Display
    i = i + 1
    Loop

Set EmailApp = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931716/add-new-lines-in-vba-email

Comment: `Set EmailApp = Nothing` should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been 15 years since I tried this, but try the modal property on the `EmailItem.Display` method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.display

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you! I also needed to move: Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) to inside the loop as the second iteration was giving a runtime error. Now all seems to work as hoped!